# Failing to test POST in Django

Tags: json, django, python-3.x, testing, post

Using Python3, Django, and Django Rest Frameworks.
Previously I had a test case that was making a POST to an endpoint.
The payload was a dictionary:

```
mock_data = {some data here}
```

In order to send the data over the POST I was doing:

```
mock_data = base64.b64encode(json.dumps(mock_data).encode('utf-8'))
```

When doing the POST:

```
response = self.client.post(
    '/some/path/here/', {
        ...,
        'params': mock_data.decode('utf-8'),
    },
)
```

And on the receiving end, in validate() method I was doing:

```
params = data['params']
try:
    params_str = base64.b64decode(params).decode('utf-8')
    app_data = json.loads(params_str)
except (UnicodeDecodeError, ValueError):
    app_data = None
```

That was all fine, but now I need to use some hmac validation, and the json I am passing can no longer be a dict - its ordering would change each time, so hmac.new(secret, payload, algorithm) would be different.
I was trying to use a string:

```
payload = """{data in json format}"""
```

But when I am doing:

```
str_payload = payload.encode('utf-8')
b64_payload = base64.b64encode(str_payload)
```

I cannot POST it, and getting an error:

```
raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
TypeError: b'ewog...Cn0=' is not JSON serializable
```

even if I do `b64_payload.decode('utf-8')` like before, still getting similar error:

```
raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
TypeError: b'\xa2\x19...\xff' is not JSON serializable
```

Some python in the terminal:

```
>>> d = {'email': 'user@mail.com'} # regular dictionary
>>> d
{'email': 'user@mail.com'}
>>> dn = base64.b64encode(json.dumps(d).encode('utf-8'))
>>> dn
b'eyJlbWFpbCI6ICJ1c2VyQG1haWwuY29tIn0='
>>> s = """{"email": "user@mail.com"}""" # string
>>> s
'{"email": "user@mail.com"}'
>>> sn = base64.b64encode(json.dumps(s).encode('utf-8'))
>>> sn
b'IntcImVtYWlsXCI6IFwidXNlckBtYWlsLmNvbVwifSI=' # different!
>>> sn = base64.b64encode(s.encode('utf-8'))
>>> sn
b'eyJlbWFpbCI6ICJ1c2VyQG1haWwuY29tIn0=' # same
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is resolved.
The problem was NOT with the payload, but with a parameter I was passing:

```
signature': b'<signature'>
```

Solved by passing the signature field like this:

```
'signature': signature_b64.decode('utf-8')
```

Thank you!